# Kalman Filter vs Regression

Tags: r, regression, kalman-filter

I want to know about the relationship between a multiple linear regression model and the Kalman Filter. Mainly, I want to know how I can write a multiple regression model using Kalman Filter. For that reason, I simulate some data and I run the code $lm(Y \sim X_1 + X_2)$ in R project. From that I take the estimated coefficients. I want now a code in R, in order to estimate the coefficients using Kalman Filter so as to compare my results.

Lets suppose that my dataset is produced by the code:

```
a=c(10,3,-5)
n=100
x=matrix(rnorm(n*2), byrow=F, ncol=2)
y=cbind(rep(1,n),x)%*%a + 2*rnorm(n)
lm(y~x[,1]+x[,2])
```

Thank you...

Comment: You should probably edit your question to emphasize the statistical aspects of your question rather than the "please give me code" aspects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for code.

Comment: If you edit your question to be about how to write a regression model in state space form it would more clearly be on topic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I need the relationship of multiple regression model and I have written about code because I want to check their relationship.

Comment: Why did you roll the edits back? If you are asking for code, your Q is off-topic here.

Comment: I did it by mistake. I do not need a code. Their relationship I need.

Comment: If you don't need code, you should perhaps edit to remove "I want now a code in R" from the question. A question aboute the connection between KF and linear regression would (imo) be on-topic, although might be a duplicate